# Warning: gmp_add(): Unable to convert variable to GMP - wrong type

Tags: php

I found out that GMP can add two very large numbers but when I am trying this:

```
<?php

echo gmp_add(153249554086588885887659875987668765, 2341595540865888858876598759859576598587);
```

I get:

> Warning: gmp_add(): Unable to convert variable to GMP - wrong type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put quotes around the numbers and it should work. GMP only accepts string or integers

```
echo gmp_add("153249554086588885887659875987668765", "2341595540865888858876598759859576598587");
```